# Change color of transparent element in GIMP

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, transparency, png

Someone created a logo for me, It's a one-color logo with some shiny effects as you see.

Can I change the color of the logo without losing transparency or brightness? And which one I can change the color of it?

[image: Logo 1 - Golden]

[image: Logo 2 - Silver]

[image: Logo 3 - Something :)]

I use GIMP 2.8.10 and PhotoShop CS6, I wish that the reply is in GIMP because I want to leave PS and go for GIMP.

Comment: Someone already created the Purple (Other color) logo but, I still want to learn :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the main color hues in an image, leaving other image features (transparency, luminosity, saturation) untouched use the `Colors->Hue Saturation` tool, and change only the `Hue` slider.

In these images, probably you will want to select the "diamond" part and invert the selection prior to doing that, so that it is not affected by the tool.

Comment: Are these instructions in GIMP or PhotoShop?

Comment: GIMP, as defined in the question title.